# Compare two Microsoft Access databases

Tags: microsoft-access, comparison

I have two Access databases that I need to compare but I don't know how I can do this.

I'm trying to compare the differences between both the structure and content (possibly limiting the comparison to tables and queries). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are three free products that might help.

[Free Database Compare 2.0](http://www.starinix.com/sqlcompare02.htm) :

> The StarInix Database Compare
>   application will allow you to compare
>   the structure of two databases and
>   display all the differences between
>   them. Supported databases include: SQL
>   Server (All Editions), MySQL and
>   Access databases. You can compare two
>   different databases, like access and
>   SQL 2000. It will also allow you to
>   create snapshots of a database and
>   compare a live database to an
>   snapshot. A database structure viewer
>   is included.

[Compare'EM Lite](http://home.gci.net/~mike-noel/CompareEM-LITE/CompareEM.htm)

> A very simple to use utility to
>   analyze a pair of related Microsoft
>   Access databases, determine what has
>   changed from one to the other, and
>   generate VBA code to propagate those
>   changes.

[Total Access Analyzer](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/BestPractices.html)

> Total Access Analyzer examines all
>   your database objects to provide
>   extensive documentation,
>   cross-reference, and application and
>   flow diagrams, with over 350
>   presentation-quality reports.

*EDIT : Please remember that this answer dates from 2009 before downvoting it.*

Comment: Total Access Analyzer did not used to be free. Is that changed now?

Comment: @David: You're right - this is an error. Only a demo is available and the limitations aren't well explained, but I suspect it doesn't do much.

Comment: CompareEm Lite sounded awesome, but it sucks.  More than one column involved in a relation?  Chokes.  Also, good luck figuring out how to enter your password to use it.

Comment: Neither Free Database Compare 2.0 or Compare'EM Lite allow you to compare .accdb files. They are both apparently hardcoded for .mdb files.

Answer (score 6):

Quite late but: with Office 2013 Professional Plus or Office 365 ProPlus, Microsoft now offers a [Database compare](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Compare-two-versions-of-a-database-Database-Compare-a969a77a-5251-4b59-84ea-74e12a135a05) tool.

---

**Edit**:
One could also use the [msaccess-vcs-integration add-in](https://github.com/joyfullservice/msaccess-vcs-integration) to export everything to text, then use any text comparison tool, or a versioning tool like Git.

Comment: Sadly, it gives very imcomplete information. It doesn't show specific differences, except for queries, only that the object was changed.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev :  see edit

Comment: Okay, the vcs integration add-in is much better

Answer (score 1):

Try the free version of [AccDBMerge](http://www.accdbmerge.net/).

Be aware of the following restrictions though:

> AccdbMerge Free provides basic data diff and merge facilities with the
> following limitations:
>
> - both tables must have compatible primary keys,
> - no more than 50 fields in each table,
> - no multivalue/attachment/binary fields.
>
> Pro version does not have these limitations. Also, it allows to compare data between files with
> different security options.